Why does the texture in this vector-transformed material bleed sideways at steep angles?
I am working on recreating the parallax effect used on the light-strips from Portal 2 (here's a YouTube Short demonstrating the effect) in Blender, but I'm running into a few issues. My current shader-node setup (based on this video about making a parallax shader in Blender) looks alright when viewed head-on or from the side, but when viewed at steep angles from above or below, the white center of the texture abruptly spreads out to cover the entire surface:

Here's my current node setup:


The whiteout is not caused by lighting or reflections, as it disappears when I disconnect the parallax node group from the image texture node. It seems to be specifically the white interior of the image texture bleeding over the dark border, for some reason I haven't been able to figure out.
Does anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?
Blend-Exchange link:


First comment of the YT video : "To get a completely flat and distortion free result when looking at the surface at sharp angles, instead of using the tangent node, you need to divide your "Distance" input before the Scale node by the Dot Product between Normal and Incoming vectors.". Feels like a deja-vu. Does it solve the issue ?

@Lutzi I already implemented that to fix a larger issue. It didn't solve the current problem.

I wasn't sure. It would help to provide your blend file with packed textures : https://blend-exchange.com/.

@Lutzi I added a link to the packed file.

@Lutzi did you have any other thoughts after looking at the .Blend file?

I took a look but couldn't find exactly where this white reflections are coming from. I've noticed it was coming from a factor value : it was more the color of the surface rather than reflections. I hope someone will be able to help you more.
